# Writing a Get Function Gives me an Attribute Error

Tags: python, django

This is my models.py

```
class Grade(models.Model):
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
```

This is my views to perform get(post is not required, I can run if post methood is required as well).

```
class GetGrade(generics. GenericAPIView):
    '''
    GET check/
    '''
    queryset = Grade.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataSerializer


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        a_grade = Grade.objects.all()
        return Response(
            data=DataSerializer(a_grade).data,
            status=status.HTTP_200
        )
```

My serializer is below:

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Grade
        fields = ("grade",)
```

Everything seems straightforward. It might be something silly that I might be doing.

```
AttributeError at /check/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `grade` on serializer `DataSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
```

**Original exception text was:**

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'grade'.
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/check/
    Django Version: 2.1.5
    Exception Type: AttributeError
    Exception Value:    Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `grade` on serializer `DataSerializer`.
    The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
    Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'grade'.
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @Shubhankar can you please share the whole stacktrace?

Comment: I have given a detailed error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about like this:

```
class GetGrade(generics.GenericAPIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        a_grade = Grade.objects.all()
        return Response(
            data=DataSerializer(a_grade, many=True).data,  # passed many=True as known argument
            status=status.HTTP_200
        )
```

The error occured because you are passing a [Queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/) through `DataSerializer`. When you called `data` method of `DataSerializer`, it was trying to get value `grade` attribute from Queryset. That is why, you need to pass `many=True`, so that, serializer knows you are passing queryset or a list a objects. If you want the serializer to process a single object, then you can do it like this:

```
class GetGrade(generics.GenericAPIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        a_grade = Grade.objects.all().first()  # it will return first object of queryset
        return Response(
            data=DataSerializer(a_grade).data, 
            status=status.HTTP_200
        )
```

Finally, a cleaner approach is to use [ListModelMixin](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listmodelmixin). For example:

```
from rest_framework import mixins, generics

class GetGrade(mixins.ListModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Grade.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataSerializer

    # thats it, no more code needed
```

Comment: The addition of many does make sense, not sure about the last recommendation though with the mixins (this recommendation didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

In your **Serailizers.py** you need to use **model** method to get the objects from your model in API:

```
class GetGrade(generics. GenericAPIView):
    '''
    GET check/
    '''
    model = Grade   # <---Add This in place queryset
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
```

Comment: I did what you recommended and the error is exactly the same. Not sure what was the reasoning behind it